# Magento 2 Order confirmation page not shown

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal, order-confirmation

When paying with PayPal Plus (Creditcards, PayPal) the user is not forwarded to the order confirmation page, but to the cart. The cart is then empty.

Comment: check server log error and magento error log, should something logged there

Comment: There are no errors. Response status code is 200. The transaction is executed, the order has been completed, but the only thing is that I don't see the order confirmation page, instead it redirects me to the cart.